# Google Analytics Management API - Python - Get list of views/profiles/accts. for a single user

Tags: python, google-api, google-analytics-api

I've searched high and low and cant seem to find an easy way to get a list of all the accounts/profile/views a certain user email/ID has access to.

I can think of getting the list of profile ID's for the account, get the view Ids for each profile then looping through each to find a regex match for the user email I'm interested in, then print that out.  But can that really be the solution?

P.s. I dont mean permission like read,write access, although that would be nice to have on the final Print.

Use case: I want to duplicate an existing user account for another user with the same level of access to profiles and views; first I'd like to know what level of access user 1 has before I can make a copy for user 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not going to be able to find all of the accounts said user has access to unless said user grants you access.   Assuming they have authenticated you to Google analytics then you can use [Account Summaries: list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list) to retrieve a list of all of the accounts they have access to.

> Lists account summaries (lightweight tree comprised of accounts/properties/profiles) to which the user has access.

request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accountSummaries
```

response

```
{
  "kind": "analytics#accountSummaries",
  "username": string,
  "totalResults": integer,
  "startIndex": integer,
  "itemsPerPage": integer,
  "previousLink": string,
  "nextLink": string,
  "items": [
    management.accountSummaries Resource
  ]
}
```

If you don't have access to that users account and they haven't granted you access.  Then your only option will probably request to check the [Profile User Links: list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/profileUserLinks/list) for each of the accounts you suspect the user to have access to.  There is no way to search for users within Management API.